# Magento PDF invoice translations

Tags: magento-1.7, theme, localisation

I have localized and translated my Magento 1.7 installation almost 100% with csv translations, and some inline translations, however in my PDF invoices translations are not taking effect.

Some parts like "Ship to", "Sold to", and then "Shipping&Handling" are not translated. Also my tax is displayed like 25.000% (should be only 25%).

Anyone have idea where can I edit this? Is there any other place besides abstract and `invoice.php` where I can change this?

Answer (score 3):

I use [Fooman PDF customiser](http://store.fooman.co.nz/magento-extension-pdf-customiser.html) on projects where I need to edit the PDF.
Works very well for me.

Also I'd like to suggest moving all your inline translations to a translation file. Keeping translations in one place makes it more manageable.

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to add that the translations from the invoice are made in `/app/locale/xx_XX/Mage_Sales.csv` and the line "Shipping & Handling Tax" in the box at the bottom should be translated in `/app/locale/xx_XX/Mage_Tax.csv`. No extensions needed!

You can view the translatable strings by searching for '__' in `/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php` and `/app/code/core/Mage/Tax/Helper/Data.php`.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Use [easyPdfInvoice](http://www.easypdfinvoice.com/) service to generate invoices and you can edit your pdf templates easly using standard html tags.